# How can I trigger a click event for a React component using his id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, click

I have a react component and I want to know how can I trigger a click event on it by clicking an image in my case. I tried with React's useRef(), but it doesn't work. Any idea how can I do this ? My code is bellow

```
import { SingleDatePicker  } from 'react-dates';

 <SingleDatePicker
    date={dateEnd} 
    onDateChange={dateEnd => handleDateEnd( dateEnd )}
    focused={this.state.focusedEnd}
    onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focusedEnd : focused })}
    id="dateEndSearchBar" 
    />

    <img
    src={calendarIcon}
    onClick={//here I want to trigger the click on SingleDatePicker}
    />
```

Comment: Your component(`SingleDatePicker`) has the `onClick` event itself?

Comment: no, it doesn't ..

Comment: So, what do you want to do with `SelectDatePicker` when `img` clicked?

Comment: I want, when the img is clicked to happen  the same thing as if I would click on the SelectDatePicker

Comment: You can add a new `state` to your states. So on `img` click event change the state and when the state change and your component render again, you have your new state and you can do everything you want with that.

Comment: But how will that trigger the click on my component ? On rerender the component won't behave like is clicked

Comment: For instance, you define a state named `isImageClicked`. when your `img` clicked you do this: `setState({ isImageClicked : true })`. When your component rerender, you have your new state. In your `SelectDatePicker` component you can write something like this: `()=> {if(isImageClicked) triggerMyAnotherEventRelatedToSelectDatePicker; setState({ isImageClicked : false)})}` and after that, at the end change your state to the default(false). As you see I set the state to the default.

Comment: The thing is that `<SelectDatePicker/>` is not a component created by me, it's imported from `react-dates`, so I think your solution would work if it was my component and I had the control over it, but I don't have that control in this situation. Can't I trigger it by ID somehow ?

Comment: I didn't find out what do you mean by trigger, yet. Would you like to call a specific method prop on  `SingleDatePicker`?

Comment: When I click on `<SingleDatePicker/>` a calendar opens for picking the date. I want that calendar to open also when I click the image

Comment: Could you please share the code when calendar opens with clicking on `SingleDatePicker`? I think it should have a state for doing that. I would like to see the code when `SingleDatePicker` cause open the calendar, I mean that the state or prop in `SingleDatePicker` when you change it and its open the calendar.

Comment: I put all the code in the question, I import the component from `'react-dates'` so it just works out of the box. I didn't write a function or state to handle the calendar opening

Comment: Please see this link, hope your problem will be solve: https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/639. Please leave a comment if after see the link, your problem have not been solved yet.

Comment: I found my answer here, thank you a lot !! I needed to us the `onFocusChange` prop of the `SingleDatePicker`.

Comment: I'm really happy to hear that. So I will post it as the answer for further references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onFocusChange` prop in `SingleDatePicker` based on this link:

http://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/639

Answer (score 1):

you could set a class for the component in `state` and modify it on the img's onClick